# Can we pass class name as parameter?

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

```
private void passClassName(String className) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = <ReadSomeJsonFile>;
    String dataSet = jsonArray.toString();
    List<className> testData = new Gson().fromJson(dataSet, new TypeToken<List<className>>() {}.getType()); 
}
```

Here I want to pass ClassName as parameter. But as that class will not be accessible with parameter. So it will not work. I already tried [similar solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17849385/passing-class-name-as-parameter). Nothing worked for me till now.

Comment: `Class.forName(className)` will return a class.

Comment: I can think of two different answer: 1. Use reflection to use the string as class, 2. Pass the class with the answer on https://stackoverflow.com/a/22774383/11817809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make this dynamic, with class given at runtime. For this to work, the compiler must be able to create an anonymous class for `new TypeToken<List<MyClass>>() {}`. That cannot be done at runtime.

Well, it can, but now you're into dynamic bytecode creation at runtime, so let's skip that super complex option. Ask another question if you want to explore that route.

Which means that the caller must create the `TypeToken` anonymous class, e.g. like this:

```
private <E> List<E> readJsonList(TypeToken<List<E>> typeToken) {
    JSONArray jsonArray = <ReadSomeJsonFile>;
    String dataSet = jsonArray.toString();
    List<E> testData = new Gson().fromJson(dataSet, typeToken.getType());
    return testData;
}
```

*Caller*

```
List<Integer> list = readJsonList(new TypeToken<List<Integer>>() {});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In place of Integer , if I need to pass some other custom Classes dynamically then how to pass those ? Ex : List<Sample1> list = readJsonList(new TypeToken<List<Sample1>>() {});